git subtree seems to be broken, I get a segfault
At my company we a have large "bundle" repository with many sub-projects combined (for historic reasons). There a sub-projects (let's call it projA) for which I have a standalone repository. Once every couple of months, I would transfer the commits of the large bundle repository into the standalone repository like this:
cd src/large-repo
git subtree push -P projA ../subtree/projA main_ST
git subtree pull --squash -P projA ../subtree/projA main_ST
git push

This has been working fine for years now, but since the large repository grows very fast, the subtree push command also takes longer and longer, up to a point where last time it took almost 1 1/2 hours to complete.
I searched for a solution and found this tread and the answer mentioned the --rejoin option. I read the man page and it made sense to me, so I tried it (after the 1 1/2 hour wait):
git subtree push --rejoin -P projA ../subtree/projA main_ST

After that I tried the push again without the rejoin and was happy to see that it calculated the differences much much quicker (< 1 Minute).
Now it's been a couple of months since then and now I wanted to do that again:
cd src/large-repo
git subtree push -P projA ../subtree/projA main_ST
git push using:  ../subtree/projA main_ST
1/941 (1289) [1289]

And now it only took 2 minutes to complete. I was happy but then I realize that there were no new commits on my standalone repository.
I tried different branch names, but the result is the same. So I tried just making a split instead but eventually it stops with a segfault (I guess that git subtree push redirects the error output to stderr)
git subtree split -P projeA/ -b new-split-test
1/941 (214) [214]
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-subtree: line 940: 12501 Done(141)               eval "$grl"
     12502 Segmentation fault      | while read rev parents; do
    if should_ignore_subtree_split_commit "$rev"; then
        continue;
    fi; parsedparents=''; for parent in $parents;
    do
        if ! should_ignore_subtree_split_commit "$parent"; then
            parsedparents="$parsedparents$parent ";
        fi;
    done; process_split_commit "$rev" "$parsedparents";
done

I created a new clone of the repository on a temp directory, but first it complained that  a commit from the subtree is not found
git clone git@our-company-gitlab:group/large-repo.git
cd large-repo
git subtree split -P ProjA --rejoin -b split-test
fatal: could not rev-parse split hash 371ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d from commit e886869b5c9a7b97888a5898e794d2e23456c60a
hint: hash might be a tag, try fetching it from the subtree repository:
hint:    git fetch <subtree-repository> 71ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d

git fetch ~/projects/subtree/projA 371ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d

git subtree split -P projeA/ -b new-split-test
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-subtree: line 940: 22815 Done(141)               eval "$grl"
     22816 Segmentation fault      | while read rev parents; do
    if should_ignore_subtree_split_commit "$rev"; then
        continue;
    fi; parsedparents=''; for parent in $parents;
    do
        if ! should_ignore_subtree_split_commit "$parent"; then
            parsedparents="$parsedparents$parent ";
        fi;
    done; process_split_commit "$rev" "$parsedparents";
done

I repeated these step on an older server running an older version of git, but I got the same result at the same place. Looking at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-subtree the command that fails seems to be git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --parents $rev $unrevs.
Looking at the error message of my test with a fresh clone of the large repository, the commit e886869b5c9a7b97888a5898e794d2e23456c60a is the commit that was generated by --rejoin all those months ago
git log e886869b5
commit e886869b5c9a7b97888a5898e794d2e23456c60a
Merge: f032a21dc1 adf848a393
Author: xxx
Date:   Wed Jul 24 18:51:55 2024 +0200

    Split 'projA/' into commit '371ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d'
    
    git-subtree-dir: projA
    git-subtree-mainline: f032a21dc10b5fac6241c129a4d347f788ac6d5d
    git-subtree-split: 371ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d


I have no idea what to fix that or why it git rev-list ends with a segfault.
I also tried
git subtree pull --squash -P projA ~/projects/subtree/projA main_ST
...
Subtree is already at commit 371ea134596757c6b760d9d50b1387017343873d.

but the result is always the same.
Does anybody know what is going on and how can I fix it?

git-subtree is maintained by the Git project. You can report bugs to: git@vger.kernel.org

@Guildenstern thanks for the email. I wonder whether this is bug or just something funny with my repository.

A segfault sounds like a bug in git(1) somewhere, maybe that git rev-list.  A segfault is a bug somewhere regardless.
